# ASP.NET MVC 4 - Wrong object updated when adding to a list

Tags: .net, list, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to build a web app with ASP.NET MVC 4, but I've been stuck for a while, and I found nothing helpful in other posts :

I have two model classes involved : the users and the groups. The users can be in as many groups as they want, and a group has a list of users (Members). When a user creates a group, he becomes the owner of this group.

My problem is that, whenever I'm trying to create a new group (and adding the current user to the member list of this new group), a previous group seems to be modified, as the current user is no longer a member of his previously created groups.

I hope that I've been understandable enough, and I'm sorry if I'm not (English is not my native language).

Here are the model classes relevant for my question :
Class UserProfile :

```
[Table("UserProfile")]
public class UserProfile
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Group> Groups { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Group> OwnedGroups { get; set; }
}
```

Class Group :

```
public class Group
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int GroupId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public virtual List<UserProfile> Members { get; set; }

    public virtual UserProfile Owner { get; set; }

}
```

And my method used to create a new group (in GroupController) :

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Group group)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            UserProfile user = db.UserProfiles.Where(u => u.UserName == User.Identity.Name).FirstOrDefault();
            db.Groups.Add(group);
            db.SaveChanges();
            group.Owner = user;
            user.OwnedGroups.Add(group);
            user.Groups.Add(group);
            group.Members = new List<UserProfile>();
            group.Members.Add(user); 
            db.SaveChanges();

            return RedirectToAction("SearchUsersToAddToGroup", new { groupId = group.GroupId });
        }
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot spot anything obvious wrong here - but i'd try and remove some redundant code and change the user get from `FirstOrDefault()` to `SingleOrDefault()` to make sure you really only have unique users in your db (your key is `UserId` but you get on username).

There is a many-to-many relationship between `Group` and `User` so you only have to maintain the relationship from one end, not both...

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Group group)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // SingleOrDefault as you're not searching on the PK
        UserProfile user = db.UserProfiles.Where(u => u.UserName == User.Identity.Name).SingleOrDefault();

        group.Owner = user;
        db.Groups.Add(group);

        user.Groups.Add(group);
        user.OwnedGroups.Add(group);

        db.SaveChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("SearchUsersToAddToGroup", new { groupId = group.GroupId });
    }
```

This may not sort out your issue, but with less code it may be easier to find.

Comment: It doesn't seems to work :
With this code, isMember is false (id is my groupId) :
`var user = db.UserProfiles.SingleOrDefault(u => u.UserName == User.Identity.Name);
Group group = db.Groups.Find(id);
var isMember = group.Members.Contains(user)`

Comment: are you using lazy loading? if not then you should be doing a `db.Groups.Include("Members").Find(id)` for the members collection to be filled....

Comment: I don't use lazy loading, but this collection seems to be filled, because the members added with `group.Members.Add(anotherUser)` show up in the collection.
It seems that I have a problem with this many-to-many relationship, because doing `user.Groups.Add(group)` doesn't do automatically a `group.Members.Add(user)`...